# Difference of the square roots of consecutive integers is equal to the reciprocal of the sum of their square roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

The difference of the square roots of consecutive integers is equal to the reciprocal of the sum of the square roots of the same integers, like shown below.

> $$\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}$$

However, I'm interested in looking at the proof for the above but I am unable to find any online or in a book. Can anyone show me?

Thank you very much

Comment: Think about $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}=  \frac{(\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x})(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}) }{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}.$

Can you proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

$$(\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x})( {\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}})=(x+1)-x=1$$